# filter out some extra text from title within html code

Tags: regex

I want to get the title from Html code I have, but with the Regex code I tried some text before and after the actual title will be extracted as well, I want to filter out those texts, and get only the title only, in this example the main title is:

> daily skin care routine for teens

```
<a data-test-id="search-guide" href="" title="Search for &quot;daily skin care routine for 
teens&quot;">
```

I have tried :

```
title="([^"]*)"
```

but it also extracts:

```
Search for &quot;
```

and

```
&quot;
```

anyone can help me out with this?

Comment: Why shouldn't `&quot;` be extracted? It is not a `"`. How is this being used, there isn't a parser? Maybe first strip `\bSearch for\b|&quot;`

Comment: `title="Search for &quot;([^"]*)&quot;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
title="Search for &quot;([\s\S]*?)&quot;
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/uyTPxD/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  title="Search for        'title="Search for "'
  "
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s\S]*?                 any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                   '"'
```